# Mouse Over Pop Up - Journey Builder

Tags: journeybuilder, popup, mousehover

I have a user that is unable to view the mouse over popups in journey builder. It is only the pop ups related to the # of emails. Green circles. The orange ones pop up without issue. It sits there and spins constantly without showing data. I've tried 3 browsers, ensured popups allowed. A salesforce rep said if he logged in as her he could view. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version of Chrome and try incognito mode.

Chrome has more support for CSS3 and Javascript.